# Regex to allow certain signed numbers after decimal separator(C#)

Tags: c#, regex, negative-number

I have the following constructor

```
public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
{
        //mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?"); 
        regex = "-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?$";
}
```

`digitsAfterZero` variable which I pass to the constructor is the number of digits after decimal separator I want the decimal to have. I want also to allow negative decimals. What do I have to change with my regex so it works?

Comment: Yes, because the number is a percentage which can be negative.

Comment: He means negative numbers

Comment: negative decimal number

Comment: You need to escape the decimal point: `\\.`. Also, why is the number of decimal places quantified as `{0,n}` instead of `{1,n}`? Surely if you have a decimal point you want at least one digit after it.

Comment: First of all, escape `.` and add `^` at the start.  `regex = $@"^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{{0,{digitsAfterZero - 1}}})?$";`. BTW, `-?` at the start already allows negative numbers.